# Bootstrap Popover on Checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Probably this question has already done, but I did't find anything so far. Is it possible to use the Bootstrap Popover on a checkbox (when I click on a checkbox for example).

I have a list of checkboxs in a table:

```
<input class="css-checkbox selectBox" data-trigger="hover" data-content="Display devices here" id="deviceCompareBox_{tmpl_var name='id'}"  type="checkbox" value="{tmpl_var name='id'}" >
```

and the relative method to initialize it:

```
$('.selectBox').popover();
```

But it doesn't work on *input* element. Of course, it does with an `<a>` element. Are there any way to fix it?

Comment: I tested it now and it works fine. Do you get some error in console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do is wrap the `input` inside a `div`, and give the `div` the popover functionality. You also need to set the height and width of the wrapper `div` to the height and width of the checkbox like so:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="checkbox-wrapper" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-content="Some content inside the popover">
    <input type="checkbox">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.checkbox-wrapper {
    height: 13px;
    width: 13px;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.checkbox-wrapper').popover();
})
```